# EF : The entity type is not part of the model for the current context using stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm working with EF5. I've used code first approach. I got an error while using stored procedure. The error is

```
"The entity type CustomProduct is not part of the model for the current context."
```

In Db there are 3 tables.

- Product

  - ProductId
  - ProductName
  - ProductDesription
- ProuctVaraint

  - ProductVaraintId
  - ProductId
  - ProductVaraintName
  - Stock
  - Size
- ProductPrice

  - ProductPriceId
  - ProudctId
  - Price

and Each entity has separate class with having all properties.

- Product.cs
- ProductVaraint.cs
- ProductPrice.cs

Here is all classes

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProductVaraint
    {
        public int ProductVaraintId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string ProdcutVaraintName { get; set; }

        public int Stock { get; set; }

        public int Size { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductPrice
    {
        public int ProductPriceId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomProduct
    {
        public int ProudctId { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public int Stock { get; set; }

        public int Size { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is stored Procedure

```
   public IList<CustomProduct> ExecuteSP()
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)(this)).ObjectContext;
        var connection = this.Database.Connection;

            //open the connection
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            //create a command object
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //command to execute
                cmd.CommandText = "GetProducts";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var result = context.Translate<CustomProduct>(reader).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                    result[i] = AttachEntityToContext(result[i]);
                reader.Close();
                return result;
            }

        }
    }



public TEntity AttachEntityToContext<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
        {

var alreadyAttached = Set<TEntity>().Local.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (alreadyAttached == null)
            {
                Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
                return entity;
            }
            else
            {
                return alreadyAttached;
            }
        }
```

I've mapped Product.cs,ProductVaraint.cs and ProductPrice.cs with DBContext but not mapped CustomProduct.cs

Now, I've made one stored procedure to return ProductName(from Product),ProductDescription(from product),Stock(from ProductVaraint),Size(from ProductVaraint) and Price(from ProductPrice).

To map this properties, I've a separate class called CustomProudct.cs that contains all those properties which is return by the stored procedure and map this class with store procedure.

There is no separate table for CustomProduct and I don't need to create extra table only for mapping sp result.

I know the causes that there is no separate table of CustomProduct and EF is trying to search in Db for this table and it does not find any table that's why it is throwing exception.

Please anyone suggest me how to do this. Is there any other way to handle this type of situation?

Comment: Code would be helpful to understand this and suggest way out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like

```
List<CustomProduct> lst = new List<CustomProduct>();
 while reader.Read()
          {
             CustomProduct cp = new CustomProduct();
             cp.ProductName = reader.GetString(0); --where 0 is the column index
             .....
             lst.Add(cp);
          }
```

I don't know what `AttachEntityToContext` does, but as the name suggests, you are trying to attach this CustomProduct to the DbContext. It will not work because this is a class you created, with no correspondent in the DB.

Comment: @DharmikBhandari I still don't understand why you want to attach this object to context. It's not possible anyway. What do you want to do with it after you attach it?

Comment: I'm trying to get result which will be return by stored procedure.Stored procedure will return specific column values like ProductName, ProductDesription,Stock,Size and Price rather than all column of all table. I need only those values in my application. So, there is no need to return values of all tables. That is why I use CustomProduct to map selected values.

Comment: In this case you don't need to attach the CustomProduct to the DbContext (again I say it's not possible. You can attach only database entities to the context). Use the code above and you will have a list with CustomProduct objects.